# Securely outputting Django's URLField in template

Tags: python, django

I am confused about how to securely output a link stored in Django's URLField. My model links something like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    article_url = models.URLField(max_length=20000, default='')
```

When I output the link from the Article class I simply do this:

views.py

```
context = {
        'article': article
    }
```

template.html

```
<a href="{{ article.article_url }}" target="_blank">
        {{ article.article_title }}
    </a>)
```

Is this safe or do I need some validation at some point?

Answer (score 0):

if by safe you mean auto-escaping you can apply escape filter on your link eg.

```
  {{ article.article_title|escape }}
```